# Testing stationarity in ARCH models using sum of coefficents

Tags: stata, stationarity, garch

I have ran an ARCH model and found the sum of the ARCH coefficients. I have been told that I can test if the model is stationary if the sum of the coefficients are less than one, however I am not sure how to test this statistically. I have thought about this, and wondered if it is recommended to use a Dickey-Fuller test and test for a unit root, or if there is another way? If anyone knows something about this, I would love to hear it!

For the record, I am using Stata to work with my data set.